# PyQt 4 - global name 'SIGNAL' is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to connect a push button signal to a callable I created, but for some reason this error keeps on popping up. I've checked to make sure QtCore is imported ... what else am I missing?

Sample code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class guiFindFiles(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        #Create window
        self.setFixedSize(400,180)
        self.setWindowTitle("Choose the files to use")

        #Create all layouts to be used by window
        self.windowLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.fileLayout1 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.fileLayout2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.fileLayout3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        #Create the prompt for user to load in the q script to use
        self.qFileTF = QtGui.QLineEdit("Choose the q script file to use")
        self.qFileButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Open")
        self.qFileButton.setFixedSize(100,27)
        self.fileLayout1.addWidget(self.qFileTF)
        self.fileLayout1.addWidget(self.qFileButton)

                    #Connect all the signals and slots
        self.connect(self.qFileButton, SIGNAL("pressed()"), self.loadFile)

        def loadFile():
            fileName = []

            selFile = QtGui.QFileDailog.getOpenFileName(self)
            print selFile
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SIGNAL` is inside `QtCore`, so the line should be:

```
self.connect(self.qFileButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("pressed()"), self.loadFile)
```

but you really should use [the new style connections](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html):

```
self.qFileButton.pressed.connect(self.loadFile)
```

And, unless you meant to differentiate a `click` from `press/release` couple, you'd better use `clicked` signal:

```
self.qFileButton.clicked.connect(self.loadFile)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the new style connections and it's working great!

Answer (score 1):

`SIGNAL` is defined inside `QtCore`, so you must use it within `QtCore` namespace if you've imported `QtCore` as a whole. So use:

```
QtCore.SIGNAL(...)
```

instead of:

```
SIGNAL(...)
```

Or you can import `SIGNAL` from `QtCore` explicitly:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this totally helped!

Comment: @Orchainu, if the answer helps - mark your question as answered so it could help another people facing same problem